# What would happen if the string content is empty for the localized ios and android strings

Tags: android, ios, xml, string, localization

I'm wondering for `Localizable.strings` and `strings.xml`, if there are empty values for certain keys, what would happen on the UI?

For example:

- IOS

  ```
  "_Workout.userloginpageheadline" = " ";
  "_Workout.userloginpagesubtitle" = " ";
  ```
- Android

  ```
  <string name="_Workout.userloginpageheadline"> </string>
  <string name="_Workout.userloginpagesubtitle"> </string>
  ```

Would the UI texts still remain default in English? Or they'll be replaced to empty strings?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: why not just create a project and find out?

Comment: Hi @DroiDev yes I'll try it out on a project eventually. Just time's pressing and I want to find the answer before I try that.

Comment: don't you think it would have been much faster to try it before posting on stack overflow and then waiting for a proper answer? i'm not trying to give you a hard time....  but questions like this seem to be more and more popular when all it takes is a few taps of the keyboard to find out yourself.

Comment: Hi @DroiDev, I'd say it's faster for me to get an answer from here. Cause I'm not very familiar with creating even the simplest ios app or android app. I'll have to follow the instructions I found online to create them and do the testing. Although I'd very much like to learn that, I have other urgent things to take care of so that I don't have the time. Like it's the end of my day and I haven't even completed the ios app cause I got other things to take care of. So I hope you can understand my situation of getting the answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

For IOS it will give empty content

```
textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"_Workout.userloginpageheadlin");
```

Equals

```
 textLabel.text = ""
```

but if _Workout.userloginpageheadlin doesn't even exits in localization file

Equals

```
 textLabel.text = "_Workout.userloginpageheadlin"
```